# Binary with 0's only

Tags: code-golf, binary

The input message consists of ASCII characters

The encoded output message consists of blocks of 0

A block is separated from another block by a space

Two consecutive blocks are used to produce a series of same value bits (only 1s or 0s):

After the ACSII character(s) have been converted to binary, go through the string:

If its a 1: add `0 0` *The last character multiplied by how many "1"s in the string consecutively after the first 1 found

Else If its a 0: add `00 0` *The last character multiplied by how many "0"s in the string consecutively after the first 0 found

## Input:

The message consisting of N ASCII characters (without carriage return)

## Output:

The encoded message

## Example

Input

```
C
```

Output

```
0 0 00 0000 0 00
```

More details and a better explanation can be found here: https://github.com/GlenDC/Codingame/blob/master/descriptions/chuck_norris.md

**Remember! This is code-golf, shortest code wins!**

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! According to the provided link, I think this should be processed as a continuous stream of bits, with exactly 7 bits per character (including leading 0's) and no separator between characters. This should be clarified within the challenge body.

Comment: Are you the originator of this challenge? If not, you should ensure you have permission to post it here, and give proper credit to that person.

Comment: The description here is rather confusing.  It seems like this is a run length encoding.  But I had to read the linked explanation before I could figure that out.